# Adding children to existing vnode

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

A question on render functions - I’m writing a render function that needs to build a tree-like structure.

I.e. I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "parentId": "1",
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "111",
              "parentId": "11",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "12",
          "parentId": "1",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need to display on the screen is a structure that effectively displays this (id in the example) but with components

```
1
|--11
    |--111
|--12
2
```

createElement() accepts an array of child nodes as the 3rd argument.  What I’m struggling with is how to add children to the node after creation of the parent component.

For example, if I create a top level menu component like this:

```
const myMenu = createElement('menu', {}, [])
```

and then subsequently create an item to go into that menu like this:

```
const myMenuItem1 = createElement('menu-item', {}, []);
```

How do I then go about adding myMenuItem1 into myMenu?

I thought this might be myMenu.children but despite passing an empty array as the children when creating the myMenu element, the children property is undefined.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I think you must have made a mistake somewhere in your experimenting. I have tested this and the `vnode.children` is an empty array in such situations. Which means you can simply `push` other vnodes in as you need:

```
render(createElement) {
    const VNode1 = createElement('div', {}, [])
    const VNode2 = createElement('h1', {}, 'This is headline')

    VNode1.children.push(VNode2)

    return VNode1
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ajobi/ernhg364/4/

Comment: That's very odd, I'll try again, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Sure, let me know how it went ;-)